# $H_0$ of a regression coefficient not equal 0?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Widely used method of testing regression coefficients for significance are tests for t-distributions with $H_0: coeff = 0$.

Is there a test/statistic that uses $H_0: coeff\ne 0$ for regression coefficients (like in KPSS vs ADF $H_0$ flip for unit root)? F-test maybe?

An example in R or Python would be useful.

**Re comments:**

Two one-sided test (TOST) was suggested as a possible solution to this problem, with the following suggestion to identify lower and upper bounds:

> It’s your domain knowledge, assessment by subject matter experts (e.g., physicians for biostatistics), values used in the literature of your subject, or sensitivity analysis (how the deviations propagate through the rest of your system). The best might a combination of those

This seems feasible in answering some question, but I doubt this can be used by a researcher of an unknown property. For this particular task -- where I try to identify [unknown] half-life -- the slope is truly unknown, transient, and widely changing measure, which is more or less meaningful when it's statistically significant in the sense of $H_0=0$, but not sensible when p values exceed say .5.

So, without confining the problem to any specific domain or problem, my question is still "How to test $H_0: coeff \ne 0$"

Comment: It's the same test.  One way to execute a best of $\beta_i=\theta$ with software that automatically tests only $\beta_i=0$ is to run the regression using $y-\theta x_i$ as the response variable.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing that out. But  I am interested in testing $\beta_i \ne 0$ as $H_0$ , not that $\beta_i = \theta$

Comment: I didn't understand you meant that, because $\beta_i\ne 0$ cannot be a null hypothesis: it doesn't lead to a sampling distribution for any useful test statistic.  Maybe you're looking for posts on [TOST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tost+regression)?

Comment: @whuber By `doesn't lead to a sampling distribution for any useful test statistic` do you mean there is no existing statistic for such a test?

Comment: I second that you’re looking for something like TOST. The part you’re not going to like about it is that you have to declare a range where your value is effectively zero, perhaps $-0.01$ to $+0.02$ (intentionally asymmetric).

Comment: @Dave I already checked TOST and it does look promising. However, how would I decide on lower and upper bound of the slope?

Comment: It’s your domain knowledge, assessment by subject matter experts (e.g., physicians for biostatistics), values used in the literature of your subject, or sensitivity analysis (how the deviations propagate through the rest of your system). The best might a combination of those. // Determining the bounds is HARD. It is even harder when people think you can show that the parameter is exactly equal to zero, but it’s probably at least a little off. Even if it is just $0.0000000001$, you will notice that not to be equal to zero.

Comment: Alternatives to TOST include interval estimates of the slope, such as confidence intervals or credible intervals (for a Bayesian approach). John Kruschke (professor and a member here) addresses this in his BEST paper: Bayesian Estimation Supersedes the t-Test.

Comment: Hi: One way to do this in R is to use the offset command in the lm call. So, if the original call for testing for $\beta = 0$  regression was lm(y ~ x ) then  lm(y ~ (offset(1) + x) will be testing  the null that $\beta_{1} = 1$. You can do ?offset in R for more details.

Comment: @Dave Updated question to address your suggestion on TOST's lower and upper bounds.